# How to share a folder in KDE Dolphin?

Tags: permissions, kde, configuration, samba, dolphin

I want to be able to share a folder in Dolphin. Right click on a folder, then go to Share tab.
Unfortunately I see a message there: "**You appear to not have sufficient permissions to manage Samba user shares**":

[image]

I am on Arch Linux, if that matters. I have installed `samba` package and I am able to manually configure a share. But I would like to be able to do it fast from gui, just like on Windows. Also, I have seen that in other distros using KDE, this Share tab actually works.

How to fix that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Samba#Enable_Usershares.
It explains the steps. But here they are. Run:

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/samba/usershares
sudo groupadd -r sambashare
sudo chown root:sambashare /var/lib/samba/usershares
sudo chmod 1770 /var/lib/samba/usershares
```

In `/etc/samba/smb.conf` add:

```
[global]
  usershare path = /var/lib/samba/usershares
  usershare max shares = 100
  usershare allow guests = yes
  usershare owner only = yes
```

Run:

```
sudo gpasswd sambashare -a your_username
sudo systemctl restart smb.service
sudo systemctl restart nmb.service
```

Log out and log back in.

Now in Share tab you can configure permissions level for your new share.

[image]

Also you can press "Show Samba status monitor" monitor and see the list of all your user shares and reconfigure them if required:

[image]